# What XML do I send for a field thats declared as nillable?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-nil

I have an application with a REST style interface that takes XML documents via POST from clients. This application is written in Java and uses XML beans to process the posted message.

The XML schema definition for a field in the message looks like this:

```
<xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" nillable="true" />
```

How do I send a null value that meets this spec?

I sent `<value xsi:nil="true" />`
but this caused the XML parser to barf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the right way of sending a nil value (assuming that the default namespace and the `xsi` namespace are set to the correct values, namely `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` for `xsi`.) so it looks like you might have come up against a bug in the CML parser you're using. What's the error message?

You might try using `xsi:nil="1"` or using separate open and close tags (`<value xsi:nil="true"></value>`) to try working around the bug.

Comment: This was exactly the information I needed. I followed your instructions and added the attribute for the xsi namespace and was then able to get the parser to accept and validate the posted XML document. Nice!

Answer (score 15):

What about `<value xsi:nil="true"></value>`? That's what's [in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#Nils).

Answer (score 1):

In the past when I've had XML elements that were null I could either not include them or send them empty so, in your case it'd be:
`<value />`

Have you tried that?

Comment: Given that the `<value>` element is typed as `xs:string`, using `<value/>` would give it a value of an empty string, rather than a null value. But it might be that an empty string will do.

Comment: JeniT: your prediction was exactly right. I received an empty string when I tried out this suggestion.